# How to prevent line breaks (general)

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I'm writing a text on C++. But often the line breaks after the first "+", so I get C+

+

This is just an example. How can I prevent line breaking of arbitrary parts in my odt doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no formatting option at the moment

Use the Unicode Character U+2060. Insert it an every point the line breaks, but it shouldn't. It glues two parts together.

Example for "C++" ( `|` represents the text cursor )

- C|++
- Press Ctrl+Shift+U
- `u` will appear on the screen
- Type in 2060
- Press Enter
- Now the line won't break between C and +.
- Move cursor: C+|+
- repeat process

Comment: Yes, that is the accepted way to prevent line breaks for characters that would otherwise cause them. It may be convenient to use *Find and Replace* to add the joiner.

Comment: Just tested, and works... The described character sequence can be added to Autocorrect so that Writer will make the change from C++ to C<u+2060>+<u+2060>+ as you type. The two pluses will initially split onto separate lines, but will rejoin as soon as the next character after the second plus is typed.

Comment: In my LibreOffice Writer this doesn't seem to work. Instead I found something similar via menu option Insert > Formatting mark > No width, no break.

Answer (score 0):

For the Unicode character called the "Word Joiner", type 2060 followed by Alt+x. The x must be lower-case.

It doesn't matter whether you type the digits on the ordinary number keys or the numerical keyboard. If you want a character such as "æ", which has the Unicode value 00E6, it doesn't matter whether you type the "E" in upper or lower case either.

As @E.vanPutten rightly says, the word joiner can also be found at Insert | Formatting Mark | No-width No Break.

In Libre Office Writer version 6.3.2.2 (2019), and presumably also in later versions, the method using Ctrl+Shift+U doesn't work.